# visual studio 2019 right click menu is too large

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Microsoft Visual Stdio Enterprise 2019. But the right click menu is too large and does not fit in screen.

[image]

I have also attached the my VS 2019 info down below.

[image]

Any idea to fix it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using multiple monitors with different DPI settings?

Comment: yes, I have two monitor connected with a laptop. But the display setting for both is same. In one monitor shows normal menu options and in other one shows extra big. Still I could not find any solutions.